# 32bit applications in Windows 10 don't start anymore

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, 32-bit

A few days ago I ran into the problem, that certain applications stopped working (like overnight). By stopped working I mean that the system doesn't attempt to even start them anymore. I get following message (a Windows 10 style alert):

```
This app can't run on your PC
To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher
```

This includes applications such as Thunderbird, Audacity, Steam and other 32-bit apps.

However 64-bit apps such as Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Ableton Live and all UWP apps seem to still work fine.

I also want to note that apps such as Spotify or Amazon Music, which I installed through the Microsoft Store, stopped working as well but without giving me the above alert (AFAIK they are Win32-based apps).

At the point in time I first discovered the error I ran Windows 10 1903. I did not investigate the problem and foolishly assumed the problem will just go away after an update to version 1909. Of course that was not the case.

things I tried: new admin account, turn off smart screen filter. but neither worked.

Here are my system specs:
Ryzen 2600X, 16GB, ASRock B450M, Radeon RX5700
Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 1909 64-bit

Any suggestions what the exact problem is and how to solve it?

Comment: Some tests: (1) Create a new admin account and test when logging in it, if this works then stop here, (2) In Settings > Update & Security > Windows Security > App & browser control, set to Off "Check apps and files category", (3) In Settings > Update & Security > Windows Security > For developers, enable "Sideload apps". (4) Right-click the `.exe` of one such app, Properties, Compatibility tab, and set "Run this program in compatibility mode for" to Windows 8.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. neither the new admin count, the security settings nor the compat mode did anything. issue still persist. don't really want to reinstall windows, since it was running pretty smooth so far and I would have to setup lots of applications. hope for other ideas.

Comment: More ideas: (1) Run `chkdsk`, (2) [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

harrymc:

> More ideas: (1) Run chkdsk, (2) sfc /scannow.

Thanks! Running `sfc /scannow` in the power shell with admin rights apparently repaired some system files. After a reboot I can start basically all applications again.